# can't compile .cpp file: undefined reference to "func_1"

Tags: c++, g++

I'am trying to compile a simple .cpp file using g++ on ubuntu.

Here are my three files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
using namespace std;

int main()

{

int a(2);

b = func2(a);     


return 0;

}
```

math.cpp:

```
#include "math.h"


int func2(int nombreRecu)

{

int valeur(nombreRecu + 2);


return valeur;

}
```

math.h:

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED

#define MATH_H_INCLUDED


int func2(int nombreRecu);


#endif // MATH_H_INCLUDED
```

But when doing this command, g++ main.cpp, I get the error: `Undefined reference to func2(int)`

Comment: hmm.  `math.h` is a standard C header.  Depending on your compiler and settings you might be including that header instead of your custom header.  I would change the file names (like `my_math.h`) and compiler again.

Comment: Same error when changing files name (from math.h and math.cpp to file.h and file.cpp for instance)

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, first of all make sure the code you show actually *have* the error you ask about. Then also include the actual error, complete, in full and unedited in the question body.

Comment: You forgot to include the `math.cpp` in the compile command.  You should have something like `g++ main.cpp math.cpp`